# javascript function called on pageload rather than when button is clicked in dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am dynamically generating an HTML table of variable length with javascript, and inside that form I am inserting a button for each row. The button should call a function when it is clicked, but right now the function is called for each row upon page load/table generation. If there are multiple buttons (since I create one for each row), each button calls the function. I know this because I have an alert with the name of the caller in upVoteA().

Here is the portion of the call that creates the button (entire function is at the bottom of this post):

```
        var tr1 = document.createElement('TR');
        var upvote = document.createElement('button')
        upvote.name = i + offset
        upvote.onclick = upVoteA(upvote.name)
        upvote.innerHTML = "Upvote link"
        tr1.appendChild(upvote)
```

Am I missing some property to change this behavior? What is wrong with my code?

Also, here is the full function I call to generate the table in case that is helpful..

```
function answerTableText(idd, offset)
{
    var answerDiv = document.getElementById("answerShow")
    while(answerDiv.firstChild){
        answerDiv.removeChild(answerDiv.firstChild)
    }

    if(qnumans_array[idd] >0)
    {

        var table = document.createElement('TABLE');

        var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
        table.appendChild(tableBody);

        for (var i=0; i<qnumans_array[idd]; i++){
            var tr = document.createElement('TR');

            var td1 = document.createElement('TD')
            td1.innerHTML = answer_array[i + offset]

            var td2 = document.createElement('TD')
            var tr1 = document.createElement('TR');
            //tr1.innerHTML = "Upvote"
            var upvote = document.createElement('button')
            upvote.name = i + offset
            upvote.onclick = upVoteA(upvote.name)
            upvote.innerHTML = "Upvote link"

            tr1.appendChild(upvote)

            var tr2 = document.createElement('TR');
            tr2.innerHTML = "Downvote"
            td2.appendChild(tr1)
            td2.appendChild(tr2)
            td1.padding = "1em"
            td2.padding = "1em"

            tr.appendChild(td1)
            tr.appendChild(td2)
            tr.style.borderBottom = "thin solid #37434E"    
            tr.style.borderTop = "thin solid #37434E"   

           tableBody.appendChild(tr);   
        }
        answerDiv.appendChild(table);

    }
    else answerDiv.innerHTML = "No answers yet."


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
upvote.onclick = upVoteA(upvote.name)
```

**calls** `upVoteA` and assigns its return value to the `onclick` property, exactly the way

```
a = foo()
```

**calls** `foo` and assigns its return value to `a`.

Instead, assign a function to it, either using an explicit wrapper:

```
upvote.onclick = function() {
    upVoteA(upvote.name);
};
```

...or using `Function#bind`:

```
upvote.onclick = upVoteA.bind(null, upvote.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
upvote.onclick = upVoteA(upvote.name)
```

You are *immediately* calling that function, and assigning its result to `onclick`. You want something like:

```
upvote.onclick = function() {
  upVoteA(upvote.name);
};
```